# Laravel dumps thounsands of html code in laravel.log file and it gets very large

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I upgraded my laravel 7 app to version 10 by installing a fresh one and moving file by file from the old version to the new one.

The App seems to be running fine but in fact I'm having two problems.

**First Problem**: In the log file is registering the error: Session store not set on request. This happens when I store data in the session with a shooping cart package called michaelbelgium/shoppingcart.

**Second problem**: Along with this error message it dumps more than 350 lines of html code into the laravel.log file making it in short time 2 or 3GB size.

This is a small part of the code that is dumping:
`{"view":{"view":"C:\\laragon\\www\\llantasypartes\\resources\\views\\layouts\\plantilla_tienda.blade.php","data":{"errors":"<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1549517616 data-indent-pad=\"  \"><span class=sf-dump-note>Illuminate\\Support\\ViewErrorBag</span> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#2008</a><samp data-depth=1 class=sf-dump-expanded> #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">bags</span>: [] </samp>} </pre><script>Sfdump(\"sf-dump-1549517616\", {\"maxDepth\":3,\"maxStringLength\":160})</script> ","exception":"<pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1947995931 data-indent-pad=\"  \"><span class=sf-dump-note>Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException</span> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#1680</a><samp data-depth=1 class=sf-dump-expanded> #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">message</span>: \"<span class=sf-dump-str title=\"68 characters\">The route storage/productos_imagenes/marcas/.jpg could not be found.</span>\"`

I looked for dump() or dd() commands missing on the project but doesn't have any of it.

The problems started after upgrading laravel.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Compare 7 to 10 https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/7.x...10.x where 3 files are from specific importance. `.env.example`, `config/app.php` and `config/logging.php`.

Comment: So seems to be a symfony error dump caused by something on the views\layouts\plantilla_tienda.blade.php view.  But I can't think of a reason it would put the whole error dump into the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Apparently, this happens when an exception is fired in the view and calls ViewException. I solved it with the steps below:

```bash
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="flare-config"
```

Change the value of `['reporting']['report_view_data']` to false in `config/flare.php`.

With this solution, you don't need to override ViewException or any file in the vendor folder.